# Laravel 4.2 Insert from Select

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, laravel-4

I am completely new to Laravel Framework. And I am using 4.2 version.

I am trying to run below sql statements through function calling from routes.php.

The page shows no error.

But there is no 'truncate' or 'insert' happend in Database.

**Here is the code in Controller funtion:**

```
  DB::statement('TRUNCATE TABLE calc2');

  DB::statement(
            "Insert into calc2
            Select groups, members, date(timestamp) as Date, count(id) as Total, sum(order) as Order
            from Order
            where order > 0 and date(timestamp) >= '$lastday'
            group by groups, members, date(timestamp)
    ");
```

I checked DB connections. I also run these query directly in MySQL. It is working fine.

I tried `DB::select` instead of `DB::statement` and I tried with Eloquent/raw too.

But still Database having 0 records only.

Thanks in advance if anyone can suggest me where I am doing mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you commiting your queries?

If not, just use `DB::commit();`

Doc: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/database#database-transactions

Comment: Hi tried with DB::beginTransaction(); in beginning  and end with DB::commit(); as per Laravel Document what you suggested. But still no no records in DB. The problem is in Laravel Document all is mentioned such as Insert, Select, Delete, Update. But there is no Insert from Select is mentioned.